# Javascript Processing in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, compiler-construction, javascript-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a JavaScript parser work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025114/how-does-a-javascript-parser-work)

How do browsers compile **Javascript** scripts? What type of compiler it used?

Comment: They don't compile it in a strict sense, but rather they interpret it.  And the various browsers all have different JS engines.  For example, Chrome has V8.

Comment: click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096907/do-browsers-parse-javascript-on-every-page-load)  to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript isn't compiled, but rather parsed and interpreted. This differs from browser to browser.

Chrome, uses [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), which happens to also be used by node.js. Internet Explorer has a proprietary engine known as [Chakra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_%28JavaScript_engine%29).

As for general rules, the [Annotated ES5](http://es5.github.com/#x7) shares some insight:

> The source text of an ECMAScript program is first converted into a sequence of input elements, which are tokens, line terminators, comments, or white space. The source text is scanned from left to right, repeatedly taking the longest possible sequence of characters as the next input element.

Answer (score 3):

The browsers don't compile javascript, it just parse the file and execute it.

Look here: [JavaScript_engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript gets interpreted; this is like compiled on the fly, while running, when needed. That's why a page with javascript errors will just work until a part of bad code gets used. the bad code block will just stop.